# Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 94 Current browser version is 93.0.4577.82

Tags: selenium

Writing a simple selenium script to click on links on aa website. The script is written like so:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

try:
    browser.get("https://www.google.com")
    print("Page title was '{}'".format(browser.title))

finally:
    browser.quit()
```

Now the issue is the actual chrome driver itself I get the following exception

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 94
Current browser version is 93.0.4577.82 with binary path /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
```

I went to the chromedriver downloads [site](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads). I still get the same error though.

Answer (score 6):

Compatibility issue.

Your `chrome driver` version is `94.0.4606.41` and this `driver` version supports `Chrome browser 94`

Please do anyone of the following.

- Update the `chrome browser` version to `94`
- Degrade the `driver` version to `93` (Download `93` version from here *https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=93.0.4577.63/*)

Answer (score 2):

This error occurred because you have different versions of Google Chrome and driver. It is better to update the driver, rather than install the old version of Google, since in the future it will be constantly updated (why do you want to use outdated technologies?).
I usually use :

```
ChromeDriverManager
```

because at any time without going to the web driver website you can simply download the driver with the following command:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

Further, using the path given by this command, you can use the freshly installed version:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\path_to_chrome_driver_executable\chromedriver.exe")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Mac run

```
brew reinstall chromedriver
```

Answer (score 1):

This made me go crazy I solved it like this we are using selenium npm module.

Run the code below and it will tell you what executable path you are using.

```
const { Builder, By, Key, util } = require("selenium-webdriver");
const chrome = require("selenium-webdriver/chrome");
console.log(chrome.getDefaultService().executable_);
```

I had installed chromedriver globally

```
npm i chromedriver -g
```

The executable path showed me it was using this and an older version.

Uninstalled this.

```
npm uninstall chromedriver -g
```

Now it started using the version I dowloaded and added to me PATH.

Download the latest chromedriver from here.

https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Add it to your path in the .zshrc file.

```
export PATH=/Users/dave/SeleniumWebdrivers:$PATH
```

Drag your downloaded drivers into this folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is another way to solve this problem. Uninstall the protarctor and reinstall it and see magic.

```
npm uninstall protractor
npm install protractor
```

[Session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports](https://medium.com/@prshannoct/session-not-created-this-version-of-chromedriver-only-supports-chrome-version-chromedrive-issue-3f17fd4e6a94)