# Get city name from a list of raw address with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have a list of address
`list_x = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']` and i want to send these value into google map search one by one.

My code here:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from time import sleep
path = r"C:/Users/admin/chromium-browser/chromedriver.exe"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = r"C:\Users\sonpn.vbi\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path, chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/maps/@10.8091781,78.2885026,7z")
sleep(2)
for index, item in enumerate(list_x, start=0):  
    Place = driver.find_element("class name", "tactile-searchbox-input").send_keys(item)
    Submit = driver.find_element("xpath", "//*[@id='searchbox-searchbutton']").click()
    result = driver.find_elements("xpath", '//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]')
    convert1 = [el.text for el in result]
    convert.extend(convert1)
    time.sleep(3)
    close = driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="sb_cb50"]').click()
```

and the error is

> WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
> (Session info: chrome=97.0.4692.71)

Please help me with this error. Thank you

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69227075/message-session-not-created-this-version-of-chromedriver-only-supports-chrome

Comment: Set the user agent to its latest version directly in code

Comment: Heading says: _Get city name from a list of raw address_ but your error is a basic error: _`WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable`_. Please [edit the question](/posts/73331949/edit) to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable (Session info: chrome=97.0.4692.71)
```

...implies that the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Possibly you are using the latest *chrome=104.0*
- But you are using *chromedriver=97.0*

So there is a clear mismatch between *chromedriver=97.0* and the *chrome=104.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current released [***Version 4.4.0***](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v104.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=104.0.5112.79/) level.
- *Chrome Browser* is updated to  current *chrome=104.0* (as per [chromedriver=104.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/104.0.5112.79/notes.txt)).

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution, you can use API, such as [Google Maps Place Results API](https://serpapi.com/maps-place-results) from SerpApi (paid API with a free plan that handles blocks and parsing on their backend).

To begin with, we create a list of the necessary addresses and a list with coordinates to them (the coordinates can be found in the URL of the address we need):

```py
# addresses from which we want to extract the name of the cities
addresses = [
    'Bälliz 22, Switzerland',
    'Blümlisalpstrasse 36, Switzerland',
    'Stauffacherstrasse 105, Switzerland',
    'Am Wasser 3, Switzerland',
    'Ringstrasse 18, Switzerland'
]

# GPS coordinates of location where you want your q (query) to be applied
# those coordinates are taken from the Google Maps URL
geo_coordinates = [
    '@46.7600484,7.6155472,14.08z',
    '@46.7810488,7.574276,14z',
    '@47.3792421,8.5218228,16z',
    '@47.4039247,8.5970111,16z',
    '@47.4139972,9.190949,13z'
]
```

Next, we loop through the lists using [`zip()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip), get the full address from API response and use [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to extract the name of the city:

```py
city_name = re.search(r'\d+\s(\w+),', results['place_results']['address']).group(1)
```

Check full code in [online IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/scrape-google-maps-few-adresses#main.py).

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import json, re, os

# addresses from which we want to extract the name of the cities
addresses = [
    'Bälliz 22, Switzerland',
    'Blümlisalpstrasse 36, Switzerland',
    'Stauffacherstrasse 105, Switzerland',
    'Am Wasser 3, Switzerland',
    'Ringstrasse 18, Switzerland'
]

# GPS coordinates of location where you want your q (query) to be applied
geo_coordinates = [
    '@46.7600484,7.6155472,14.08z',
    '@46.7810488,7.574276,14z',
    '@47.3792421,8.5218228,16z',
    '@47.4039247,8.5970111,16z',
    '@47.4139972,9.190949,13z'
]

for address, coordinates in zip(addresses, geo_coordinates):
    params = {
      "api_key": "...",               # serpapi key, https://serpapi.com/manage-api-key
      "engine": "google_maps",        # SerpApi search engine
      "type": "search",               # list of results for the query
      "google_domain": "google.com",  # google domain
      "q": address,                   # query
      "hl": "en",                     # language
      "ll": coordinates               # GPS coordinates
    }
    
    search = GoogleSearch(params)     # where data extraction happens on the backend
    results = search.get_dict()       # JSON -> Python dict
    
    city_name = re.search(r'\d+\s(\w+),', results['place_results']['address']).group(1)
    print(f'City name: {city_name}')
```

Example output:

```
City name: Thun
City name: Heimberg
City name: Zürich
City name: Dübendorf
City name: Neuenhof
```

There's a [Using Google Maps Place Results API from SerpApi using Python](https://serpapi.com/blog/using-google-maps-place-results-api-from-serpapi/) blog post if you need a little bit more code explanation and how to extract other data.

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.